# Selenium Webdriver (Java) : Unable to search text in certain buttons

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate clicking of a button, and I am using the following code to do that :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+deno+"')]")).click();
```

where `deno` is simply a variable.

When `deno` = 14 Diamonds, the click action can be automated. The following is the screenshot of the 14 Diamonds' location.

[image]

However, when `deno` = 42 Diamonds, the button was not clicked and no error (such as element not found) was displayed. The following is the screenshot of the 42 Diamonds' location.

[image]

I am very new to this, so hope to have some advice on what I may have done wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged and tried?

Comment: @Nandan A Yeap I did. When I set demo = 42 Diamonds, and run in both normal and debug mode, it just skipped the simulation of clicking the 42 Diamonds button. I did try to capture element error, but it is not returning anything.

Comment: Please try this `//div[contains(@aria-labelledby,'42 Diamonds')]` and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be new line character in between the text.
Can you try below xpath to click on button.

```
//div[contains(@area-labelledby,'"+deno+"')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, I am getting "Element not found" error.

Comment: can you try this xpath in browser dev tool first and check Is it working? 

//div[contains(@area-labelledby,'42 Diamonds')]

Comment: I tried as per recommended, but I am getting Element not found for both 14 Diamonds and 42 Diamonds.

Comment: In my view reason could be element is not loaded properly before click event. **//div[contains(@area-labelledby, '42')]** or **//div[contains(@area-labelledby, 'Diamonds')]** can you try above xpaths in browser dev tool and check if it locate the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than searching for the elements via text, you can use the class names and create a css selector, get all the web elements which pertain to the text buttons and then perform what ever actions you want to perform.

If you see the HTML, that you've provided, then you can see that the buttons have common classes. - `selection_tile__text d_flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center` [Please correct if there is any spelling mistake since I manually typed all these classes]

Now you can get all the buttons using the classes from above -

```
List<WebElement> allBtns = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("selection_tile__text.d_flex.flex-column.justify-content-center.text-center"));

   for (WebElement btn : allBtns){
               btn.click().   // will click on every button

              // do something else
               }
```

Comment: Really appreciate your effort @demouser123. ANd really thanks for chipping in. May I know, if I were to simulate click of one single button instead of clicking on every button, may I seek you advice on how to do that, base on your coding above ?

Comment: Use index like `btn[0]` or `btn[1]` for a single btn

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is absolutely right. 2 things we need to take care for no such element exception.

1. Please make sure your element is inside the frame structure.
2. If no frame, you are trying to click the 12 diamonds element before the page loads. please add wait conditions until the visibility of the element.

   ```
   By tmpBy = By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+deno+"')]");
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(tmpBy));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(tmpBy));
   driver.findElement(tmpBy).click();
   ```